# How can I only receive data from selected serial numbers from json api with python script

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, prometheus

How can I only receive data from selected serial numbers
or alternatively add a list of serial numbers to exclude ?
ie)"serialNumber": "121718037628", has been dead for about 2 months now 
or maybe auto exclude data that has not been updated for a long period of time 
using "lastReportDate": 1549920259,

using prometheus to scrape the metadata

the stream from then enphase microinverter controller looks like this
http://envoy/api/v1/production/inverters (local network )

```
[
  {
    "serialNumber": "121718037628",
    "lastReportDate": 1549920259,
    "devType": 1,
    "lastReportWatts": 18,
    "maxReportWatts": 18
  },
  {
    "serialNumber": "121718037534",
    "lastReportDate": 1555635154,
    "devType": 1,
    "lastReportWatts": 108,
    "maxReportWatts": 187
  },
  {
    "serialNumber": "121718037683",
    "lastReportDate": 1555635148,
    "devType": 1,
    "lastReportWatts": 117,
    "maxReportWatts": 197
  },
```

I have tried added this in

```
ignore_list = ['121718037628']
       for pattern in ignore_list:
           if fnmatch( pattern):
                should_ignore = True
```

and tried with

```
[f for f in serial if not any(a in f.split() for a in faultyunit)]
```

and this is the original python code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -f

import os
import time
import json
import requests
import threading
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
from prometheus_client import start_http_server, Gauge


host = os.getenv('ENVOY_HOST')
password = os.getenv('ENVOY_PASS')

user = 'installer'
auth = HTTPDigestAuth(user, password)
marker = b'data: '


serials = {
    121718037663: '#1',
    121718037534: '#1',
    121718037513: '#1',
    121718037414: '#1',
    121718037683: '#1',
    121718037593: '',  
    121718037695: '#1',
    121718037872: '#1',
    121718037601: '#1',
    121718037876: '#2',
    121718037698: '#2',
    121718037881: '#2',
    121718037584: '#2',
    121718037703: '#2',

}


stream_gauges = {
    'p': Gauge('meter_active_power_watts', 'Active Power', ['type', 
'phase']),
    'q': Gauge('meter_reactive_power_watts', 'Reactive Power', 
['type', 'phase']),
    's': Gauge('meter_apparent_power_watts', 'Apparent Power', 
['type', 'phase']),
    'v': Gauge('meter_voltage_volts', 'Voltage', ['type', 'phase']),
    'i': Gauge('meter_current_amps', 'Current', ['type', 'phase']),
    'f': Gauge('meter_frequency_hertz', 'Frequency', ['type', 'phase']),
    'pf': Gauge('meter_power_factor_ratio', 'Power Factor', ['type', 'phase']),
}

production_gauges = {
    'activeCount': Gauge('production_active_count', 'Active Count', ['type']),
    'wNow': Gauge('power_now_watts', 'Active Count', ['type']),
    'whToday': Gauge('production_today_watthours', 'Total production today', ['type']),
    'whLastSevenDays': Gauge('production_7days_watthours', 'Total production last seven days', ['type']),
    'whLifetime': Gauge('production_lifetime_watthours', 'Total production lifetime', ['type']),
}

consumption_gauges = {
    'wNow': Gauge('consumption_now_watts', 'Active Count', ['type']),
    'whToday': Gauge('consumption_today_watthours', 'Total consumption today', ['type']),
    'whLastSevenDays': Gauge('consumption_7days_watthours', 'Total consumption last seven days', ['type']),
    'whLifetime': Gauge('consumption_lifetime_watthours', 'Total consumption lifetime', ['type']),
}

inverter_gauges = {
    'last': Gauge('inverter_last_report_watts', 'Last reported watts', ['serial', 'location']),
    'max': Gauge('inverter_max_report_watts', 'Max reported watts', ['serial', 'location']),
}


def scrape_stream():
    while True:
        try:
            url = 'http://%s/stream/meter' % host
            stream = requests.get(url, auth=auth, stream=True, timeout=5)
            for line in stream.iter_lines():
                if line.startswith(marker):
                    data = json.loads(line.replace(marker, b''))
                    print(data)
                    for meter_type in ['production', 'net-consumption', 'total-consumption']:
                        for phase in ['ph-a', 'ph-b']:
                            for key, value in data.get(meter_type, {}).get(phase, {}).items():
                                if key in stream_gauges:

stream_gauges[key].labels(type=meter_type, phase=phase).set(value)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print('Exception fetching stream data: %s' % e)
            time.sleep(5)


def scrape_production_json():
    url = 'http://%s/production.json' % host
    data = requests.get(url).json()
    production = data['production']
    print(production)
    for each in production:
        mtype = each['type']
        for key in ['activeCount', 'wNow', 'whLifetime', 'whToday', 'whLastSevenDays']:
            value = each.get(key)
            if value is not None:
                production_gauges[key].labels(type=mtype).set(value)
    consumption = data['consumption']
    print(consumption)
    for each in consumption:
        mtype = each['measurementType']
        for key in ['wNow', 'whLifetime', 'whToday', 'whLastSevenDays']:
            value = each.get(key)
            if value is not None:
                consumption_gauges[key].labels(type=mtype).set(value)



def scrape_inverters():
    url = 'http://%s/api/v1/production/inverters' % host
    data = requests.get(url, auth=auth).json()
    print(data)
    for inverter in data:
        serial = int(inverter['serialNumber'])
        location = serials.get(serial, '')
        inverter_gauges['last'].labels(serial=serial, 
location=location).set(inverter['lastReportWatts'])
        inverter_gauges['max'].labels(serial=serial, 
location=location).set(inverter['maxReportWatts'])


def main():
    start_http_server(8000)
    stream_thread = threading.Thread(target=scrape_stream)
    stream_thread.setDaemon(True)
    stream_thread.start()
    while True:
        try:
            scrape_production_json()
            scrape_inverters()
        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception fetching scrape data: %s' % e)
        time.sleep(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and I have tried adding this

```
}

ignorelist = {
    121718037628,
}

for inverter in data:
     if inverter['serialNumber'] in ignorelist:
        continue
         serial = int(inverter['serialNumber'])
```

but then it skips all of the inverters

also tried this approach

```
json_response = [
{
}
]
```

but unsure how to get that as what its read from the API

```
ignore_set = {'121718037628',} 

for inverter in json_response:
    if inverter['serialNumber'] not in ignore_set:
        print(inverter)
```

Finally Solved it , Thanks for all the help

```
ignorelist = {
'121718037628','121718037534'
}

for inverter in data:
if inverter['serialNumber'] not in ignorelist:
    print(inverter)
    serial = int(inverter['serialNumber'])
    location = serials.get(serial, '')
```

Comment: I've just woken up so not following - you are trying to exclude from the request or filter out of response?

Comment: Thanks for the comment and goodmorning, , I guess I can try looking into exclude, the output is normally like this: inverter_last_report_watts{location="",serial="121718037628"} 18.0  , I am not wanting an output if it is number "121718037628"

Comment: but if it only fetched data from serials contained in this section: serials = {
    121718037663: '#1', this would be great as they are manually entered to set the array they are on for the graphing

Answer (score 1):

```
ignorelist = {
'121718037628','121718037534'
}

for inverter in data:
    if inverter['serialNumber'] not in ignorelist:
        print(inverter)
        serial = int(inverter['serialNumber'])
        location = serials.get(serial, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps check serial is in ignore list then skip processing further for the device

```py
for inverter in data:
    if inverter['serialNumber'] not in ignorelist:
        serial = int(inverter['serialNumber'])
```

Comment: thanks I had tried that before and it would crash , unless I am doing something wrong with setting ignore list ? (sorry I can not work out the formatting for this )         ignorelist = {
    121718037628,
}

Comment: so apparently I wasted my day because of an IndentationError , thanks for confirming I was on the right track

Comment: how ever it now ignores everything  <br/>    ` ignorelist = {  <br/>        121718037628,  <br/>    }  <br/>`(sigh I still can not work out how to reply with code formatting how do you drop a line without it sending )

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example of a ignore list as a string whatever I do still skips all inverters : Exception fetching scrape data: name 'loop' is not defined